# unexpected page scroll on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

there is a horizontal scroll bar but ı don't understand why does it scroll. I want the content to fill screen.

[image]

```html
<section class="who" data-aos="fade-in">
        <img class="bg-img1"src="{{asset('images/wh.png')}}" alt="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-1 order-2" data-aos="fade-right">
                   
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 order-lg-2 order-1" data-aos="fade-left">
                    <h2> WHO AM I? </h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
                        <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
                        <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
                        <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
                        <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                        </li>
                        <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: add `col-md` and `col-sm` class might help...

Comment: it's most likely the image or the `bg-img` class. Make sure it has max-width: 100%

Answer (score -1):

The scrollbar appears because you did not set the small col grid for your `div`.
You can try setting:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-1 order-2" data-aos="fade-right">
                   
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-2 order-1" data-aos="fade-left">
   <h2> WHO AM I? </h2>
   <ul>
      <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
      <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
      <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
      <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
      <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
      <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```